# User profile deployment questions

Tags: deployment, custom

I'm trying to deploy a bunch of changes to user profiles from one devpro sandbox to a full copy sandbox, then to production. However, I am getting the following error due to a few master-detail relationships:

> Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Manage All ServiceAccountAssociations depends on
>   permission(s): Read All Accounts (Companies) Permission Read All
>   ServiceAccountAssociations depends on permission(s): Read All Accounts
>   (Companies)

However, if I try to turn on View All Data on the contact object, I get the error above, and if I turn on view All data on the account object I get the following error:

> Please fix the following:
>
> Permission Manage All ServiceContactAssociations depends on
>   permission(s): Read All Contacts Permission Read All
>   ServiceContactAssociations depends on permission(s): Read All Contacts

I have to cancel out of each to continue so I can never save it. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's due to Master-Detail relationship.If you don't specify permissions for the master object then you shouldn't specify "view all" or "modify all" on the detail object as permissions on child is controlled by parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify any permissions on the `ServiceAccountAssociations` and `ServiceContactAssociations` objects when these are the detail in a Master-Detail relationship.

These permissions are controlled by the Master object and the Detail object inherits the permissions from its master.

Comment: so how do i fix this?

Comment: all i was really trying to do was rename the profile and it won't let me.